# Youtube_DL no attribute 'from_url'

Tags: python, discord.py, youtube-dl

I am trying to create a discord bot that plays music. The bot joins and disconnects channels but when I play it returns this:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: type object 'YTDLSource' has no attribute 'from_url'
```

I have tried to take directly from the docs with no success

```
ytdl_format_options = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'outtmpl': '%(extractor)s-%(id)s-%(title)s.%(ext)s',
    'restrictfilenames': True,
    'noplaylist': True,
    'nocheckcertificate': True,
    'ignoreerrors': False,
    'logtostderr': False,
    'quiet': True,
    'no_warnings': True,
    'default_search': 'auto',
    'source_address': '0.0.0.0' # bind to ipv4 since ipv6 addresses cause issues sometimes
}

ffmpeg_options = {
    'options': '-vn'
}

ytdl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ytdl_format_options)

class YTDLSource(discord.PCMVolumeTransformer):
    def __init__(self, source, *, data, volume=0.5):
        super().__init__(source, volume)

        self.data = data

        self.title = data.get('title')
        self.url = data.get('url')


c = Bot(command_prefix = '/', help_command=None)
players = {}


@c.command()
async def join(ctx):
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    await channel.connect()

@c.command()
async def leave(ctx):
    await ctx.guild.voice_client.disconnect()

@c.command()
async def play(ctx, *, url):
    async with ctx.typing():
            player = await YTDLSource.from_url(url, loop=self.bot.loop)
            ctx.voice_client.play(player, after=lambda e: print('Player error: %s' % e) if e else None)

            await ctx.send('Now playing: {}'.format(player.title))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your YTDLSource only has a constructor and is missing the from_url method. If you add this method found in the docs, it should work.

```
@classmethod
async def from_url(cls, url, *, loop=None, stream=False):
    loop = loop or asyncio.get_event_loop()
    data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: ytdl.extract_info(url, download=not stream))

    if 'entries' in data:
        # take first item from a playlist
        data = data['entries'][0]

    filename = data['url'] if stream else ytdl.prepare_filename(data)
    return cls(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(filename, **ffmpeg_options), data=data)
```